# Issue when I copy a char array to another, using a template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, copy, char

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T1, class T2>
void copy2(const T1 source[], T2 destination[] , int size){
    for (int i=0 ; i < size ; ++i){
        destination[i]=static_cast<T1>(source[i]);
    }
}



int main() {

    const char one[] = "hello";
    char two[5];

    cout << "one: " << one << endl;
    cout << "two: " << two << endl;

    copy2(one, two, 6);

    cout << "one: " << one << endl;
    cout << "two: " << two << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

but it outputs:

*one: hello*

two:

one:

two: hello

Moreover, the array "one" is const, and therefore shouldn't be changed.

PS: When I initiate the array "two" in the following way, it works (but WHY??):

```
 char two[8];
```

However when I initiate it in both of the following ways, I get weird errors:

```
 char two[6];
```

or

```
 char two[7];
```

Comment: You have both `copy2` and `copyStuff`. Which is it?

Comment: sorry I just mispelled that. But that isn't the problem.

Comment: The array `one` is `const`, true, but that doesn't mean it can't be modified.  It means trying to do so is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to copy the source buffer to destination you need the destination buffer big enough to hold the source buffer.

```
char two[5];
```

does not have enough space to store `H`,`E`,`L`,`L`,`O`,`\0` ---> size is `6`
So, Your destination array `two` should atleast have an size of `6`, Otherwise your program writes beyond the bounds of the array and cause an Undefined Behavior.

Also, You should initialize your source buffer and NULL terminate it. Otherwise it contains junk characters.

```
char two[6]={0};
```

With the above mentioned modifications your **[program works](http://codepad.org/zuWYIjAE)** as desired for me.

Comment: I am assuming it is a typo that you call `copystuff()` and not `copy2()` in the code given in Q.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I still have to clarify why does it erase the value of the "one" array, when I do not initialise my source buffer to NULL. Because even if I set the destination buffer size to 6, without initialising my source buffer to NULL I get:


    one: hello
    two: 
    one: hello
    two: hellohello

Comment: @user1155340: If your destination buffer has a size(`5`) less than source(`6`) then writing `6` bytes to destination buffer results in writing data beyond the bounds of the destination buffer.Probably, the source buffer is placed on stack right after the destination buffer and the extra `1` byte which contains `\0` gets written in source buffers location.This makes your source buffer NULL.This is what might be happening but anyways overwriting the bounds of an array results in **Undefined Behavior** & your program can show any such weird behaviors,which may or may not be explained.

Comment: @Als Basically everything I said in my answer :)

Comment: @Marlon: Not Really. You missed out on saying that this is Undefined Behavior and actually any behavior could have been seen, While We can only guess at what might happen Theoretically, an UB might result in to anything that need not be even explainable.The behavior post an UB inherently does not warrant any explanation whatsoever.Yes my answers for Q's displaying UB usually do not provide any explanations for that because such behaviors can never be relied upon to base your programs on.Theres only one rule avoid writing any code with UB & if you don't you are doomed with no explanation.

Answer (score 6):

My best guess is that `two` and `one` are on the stack next to each other like this:

```
  t   w   o   -   -   o   n   e   -   -    -
 --------------------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   | h | e | l | l | o | \0 |
 --------------------------------------------
```

Since you are overflowing `two`'s buffer by passing size 6 to `copy2` when `two` has size 5, the memory will end up like this:

```
  t   w   o   -   -   o    n   e   -   -   -
 --------------------------------------------
| h | e | l | l | o | \0 | e | l | l | o | \0 |
 --------------------------------------------
```

Which is why `two` appears to hold "hello" and `one` shows nothing (since two overran its buffer and now the null terminator is the first character in `one`).

Comment: It is very likely that this is what happens, but it is as much likely that this might not be happening at all.The only definite truth here is it is an **Undefined Behavior**.